How to deal with intensity difference between different colors
I need a color palette with constant intensity.
My problem is that the perceived ratio between full green and full blue on a computer display is huge (To my eyes and on my setup close to 100:6). This means that it is impossible to have a fully saturated blue. It is possible to achieve identical intensity, as well as identical saturation, however, this causes green to look almost gray. If green has full intensity and saturation, the saturation of blue has to be low.
How to deal with the huge difference in intensity?

One possible solution is to use a colour space to help calculate the colours based on human perception. One of these you might find useful is HSLuv, and what's nice about this colour space is it's built into the free vector image editor Inkscape.
HSLuv is a type of HSL colour space, but is based on human colour perception experiments.
Below are some examples using this colour space to try to keep the lightness of fully saturated colours the same across a row of colours.
The top row is the starting point, with full saturation pure RGB colours
The other rows are basically the same colours but with the L component set to 32, 50, 75, and 85 respectively

I created this using Inkscape, and below is a screenshot of the Inkscape HSLuv colour wheel and selectors that I used


Another useful link. n_n

So the suggestion is to maximize the saturation per color, rather than using the saturation that makes blue as bright as green.

@user877329 If your intent is to have a colour palette that has colours which look similar in brightness to the human eye - you have to take into account how the human eye perceives colour. Within the limits of human colour perception there is no saturation value that can make pure blue the same brightness as pure green. You have no option but to change their brightnesses to compensate.

@BillyKerr Yes, but the question was about what to sacrifice. I can get equal saturation if I accept d8c9b2 as yellow. But maybe it is better to allow different saturation (as appears to be the case in HSLuv.

@user877329 - You have no option given the constraints of wanting the colours appear to be the same brightness across the palette. If you change the saturation the colours will simply lose their colour and tend towards grey.  If you can live without such strict constraints, and make compromises, then sure, you can have more options. No laws are being broken. Colour use is subjective. You can do what you want.

@user877329 You can simply use the HSLuv generated values as a starting point and tweak them for aesthetic purposes. See an example here

However it's worth noting there is no formula for aesthetic choice. That would require some degree of human intervention.  Note also that there are other colour space options out there. HSLuv is not the only one.


This means that it is impossible to have a fully saturated blue

No. You can. Simply make a #0000FF or whatever color mode you have and by definition it is a fully saturated blue.

How to deal with the huge difference in intensity?

Probably by evolving into a different species. Human vision is simply more sensitive to green spectrum than blue.

But to be specific on the advice you might consider cian tones, that add some green.
And use not a desaturated green. Green does not need to be desaturated per se, but darker, something like #00AA00 or similar.
And you always need contrast, in this case, lightness contrast, so having a lighter color than the other is not a bad thing, use it to your advantage.
If you are making webpages, you probably want to look at the OKLCH color model.
https://oklch.com/#70,0.1,101,100
